# google app engine: while using gcloud app deploy ,you do not have permission to access project

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using cloud app deploy but it comes:

Server responded with code [400]:
  Bad Request Unexpected HTTP status 400.
  Failed Project Preparation (app_id='b~eloquent-env-168317'). Out of retries.  Last error: Temporary error occurred while verifying project: TEMPORARY_ERROR: Operation does not satisfy the following requirements: billing-enabled {Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'eloquent-env-168317' to proceed., https://console.developers.google.com/project/eloquent-env-168317/settings}
com.google.api.management.server.common.exceptions.ServiceManagementNonRetriableStorageException: Operation does not satisfy the following requirements: billing-enabled {Billing must be enabled for activation of service '' in project 'eloquent-env-168317' to proceed., https://console.developers.google.com/project/eloquent-env-168317/settings}
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
Building and pushing image for service [default]
Some files were skipped. Pass `--verbosity=info` to see which ones.
You may also view the gcloud log file, found at
[/Users/majnun/.config/gcloud/logs/2017.05.22/01.24.54.321942.log].
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) You do not have permission to access project [eloquent-env-168317] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

what's wrong, how can I fix it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

On 2017-May-21 your project was suspended. You should have received an email explaining the reason for the suspension, and the steps you need to follow to un-suspend your project. You can find out more information in the [Project Suspension Guidelines](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-suspension-guidelines).

You can see in the error you provided "**Billing must be enabled for activation of service..**". Therefore, submitting the [Account Verification form](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/verify) should be all you need to do.